# Tricky Rewrite rule for removing extentions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rule for removing php extensions

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ en/$1.php [NC,L]
```

Now with these rules it works when I access domain.com/abc .. But the problem is that, when I manually access domain.com/abc.php .. it also works.

What I want is that domain.com/abc.php should also redirect to domain.com/abc.

How can I achieve this ?

In short, in any case I want php extension to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Rule, which will redirect all *.php to uri-s without extension:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ en/$1.php [NC,L]
```